Window is throwing error pop window for couple of seconds on launching of electron window
When I am launching electron window it is throwing warning message in the pop window as below screen shot to wait with below error in the terminal. This pop is staying on the window for couple of seconds and disappearing.
I am not very sure but seems as because window is taking time to load in that case it is throwing error pop window.
I would appreciate if anyone can provide solution to disable this error message or suppress it. Thanks in advance.
NOTE:

show configuration of BrowserWindow object must to be true.

Terminal error:
MESA: error: ZINK: vkCreateInstance failed (VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER)
glx: failed to create drisw screen
failed to load driver: zink
libva error: vaGetDriverNames() failed with unknown libva error
[20857:1204/122336.020236:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
MESA: error: ZINK: vkCreateInstance failed (VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER)
glx: failed to create drisw screen
failed to load driver: zink


